# Discord repeat bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I want to make a bot that repeats what someone says and delete his original msg right away.
I don't want to use a prefix for it.

Example, some type a random message: "This is a message" & the bot reply: "@user This is a message" and then the original message get deleted.

I also want it to be in a specific channel, because if not, it will mess up the whole server.
I'm not sure how to make this bot so I made a ping pong bot for a template:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!ping')) {
    message.reply('pong!');
  }
});

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('I am ready!'); 
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't for us writing code for you. If you have a specific problem with your code, that's when we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what happens when you delete the message and reply on it, but you could try something like that:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


// set your chanel id here!
const channel = "my-channel";


client.on('message', message => {
    if (client.user.id !== message.author.id && message.channel.id == channel) {

        // echo reply
        message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel).send(`@${message.author.username} ${message.content}`);

        // delete message
        message.delete();

    }
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.login('token');
```

As @Mootje has pointed out:

If you use discord.js v12 use:

`` message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel).send(`@${message.author.username} ${message.content}`); ``

instead of

`` message.guild.channels.get(channel).send(`@${message.author.username} ${message.content}`); ``

Comment: I get an error: ```TypeError: message.guild.channels.get is not a function```

Comment: @Mentalix Try using `message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel).send...`, see my updated answer

Comment: well it's working, but it's working really weird.. it spamming it, and it mentions the bot itself

Comment: Added a check if the messages comes from a bot, see updated code: "if statement"

Comment: Yayy it's working.. but for some reason when it mentions, the user is not clickable it's like @user

Comment: and btw it deletes messages from other channels. how can I make it so the bot will only be active on a specific channel

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want every time a user says something, his original message needs to be deleted and the bot should send a message with the original message content.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready!'); 
 });

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!ping')) {
    message.reply('pong!');
  } 

   message.reply(message.content);
   message.delete()
});


client.login('token');
```

If you want the bot to send the message only in one specific channel you can use this

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready!'); 
 });

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!ping')) {
    message.reply('pong!');
  }

  let channelID = "your-specific-channel-id";
  message.guild.channels.get(channelID).send(message.content); 
  message.delete()
});
```

If you're using Discord.js V12 you need to change:

```js
message.guild.channels.get(channelID).send(message.content);
```

to

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(message.content);
```

**UPDATE**
This is the code without all the unnecessary code(requested in the comments)

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready!'); 
 });

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    /* The channel the bot uses to "send" messages in */
    let sendChannelID = "channel-id";

    /* The channel the bot checks messages from */
    let activeChannelID = "channel-id"

    if(message.channel.id == activeChannelID){
        message.delete()
        message.guild.channels.cache.get(sendChannelID).send("<@" + message.author.id + ">: " + message.content); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want the ping and pong to be in the code, it's just an example for the idea of this bot.

Comment: You can just remove that command, it shouldn't make any difference in code.

Comment: u really described the bot like I want it to be, I will highly appreciate if you can send me the complete code for the bot without unnecessary things. thanks!

Comment: I edited the original answer with the code you need at the bottom @Mentalix

Comment: I see it's working, but it's spamming it, and it's not mentions the user

Comment: it's working but unfortunately, it's also deletes and send messages from other channels

Comment: Should be fixed now in the latest update, you'll need to give the correct channel id to `activeChannelID` so it knows which channel he needs to check and ignore all other channels.

Comment: You're a real king!

Comment: I assume you got it working, if so you may close this question and select the right answer so once someone else has the same issue he can easily find the right answer.

Comment: No problem, just a question, is it possible to make each message from the bot divided as a new message, because if I make 2 messages in a row it shows as one message

Comment: It's a separate message already, Discord just show messages from the same author that were sent in a short period of time as one. If you hover over it with your mouse you can see that it's not just one message. Nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Alright yeah I see, can I add maybe a manual separator to the code? like ------------------------ under everything?

Comment: I don't recommend that as a solution, yet you can use it by adding:
`message.guild.channels.cache.get(sendChannelID).send("----------------------");`
Under the existing line that looks almost the same as this one

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help me! got bless you